# How to extract the both row data in a group in Google sheet?

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the VLOOKUP function to extract data from one google sheet to another. However, the original data contains row grouping, as shown in this [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXxUw.png). The VLOOKUP function only extracts the first row and ignores the rest. Is there any function that can help me extract all the rows, not just the top one?

Thanks.

Comment: Use [filter()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197). [this article](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-vlookup-return-all-matches/) should be of help.